# Translate focal point of parallel laser beams on single plane using a galvanometer

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I am trying create a focal point of multiple parallel rays and move that point along a perpendicular plane somehow using the rotation of a lens or mirror via a galvanometer. It is a little hard to explain so I have included a diagram.

[image]

I understand that I could use a converging lens and rotate it to move the focal point, however this would move the point in a circular motion. Does anyone have any ideas on a setup where the focal point could be moved along the plane via rotation of a lens and/or mirror arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I have found the type of lens I was after. It is called an f-theta scanning lens.

Comment: Could you write more from it, with references?